# Interrrupt infinite loop in elisp - ielm buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to interrupt the infinite loop & resume command prompt in emacs, ielm buffer

```
(loop () (print 1))
```

presently, to come out of this mess, i kill emacs & restart it...

Answer (score 2):

Use the quit command, bound to `C-g` (Ctrl-G for the uninitiated).